# Why is there no badge for questions with upvotes?

Tags: support, questions, badge-request, voting

Given the recent push to get more (up)votes on questions, why are there no badges for having a question with many upvotes?

Comment: [Nice Question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/20/nice-question) `->` [Good Question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question) `->` [Great Question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question)?

Comment: => We need better badge descriptions! (Make them a wiki!?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the description for the Question badges uses the word "score" instead of "upvote".

Thanks to Tim Stone for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Note that a "score" of 10 could mean 100 upvotes and 90 downvotes `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: a "score" could also mean "net upvotes * 10". See also http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2200/i-do-not-understand-some-of-the-badges </vindication>